# dynamic divisions creation and input fields change not happening based on condition

Tags: javascript, html

I have a division with a table and that table contains one row initially, I wrote a function to add rows dynamically, if user clicks on 'add row'.

and I'm using another function to create another division if user wants to add another, with 'add division'.

But, 'add row' function is working only for division one but not effecting respective division.

Any help regarding this issue ?

Comment: I can't tell from your description what the problem is or what you're trying to do. Please provide code samples showing off what you're currently doing and what isn't working.